# Generating function from the infinitesimal generator of a continuous-time markov chain?

Tags: markov-process, moment-generating-function, probability-generating-fn

Summary: The basic goal is to find the time evolution of the probability generating function (or the moment generating function or the characteristic function if you prefer) for a continuous-time markov chain with a finite number of states.

**To set notation for a particular time period:**  let $X$ be a random variable with a discrete number of states $n = 1,\ldots N$.  Let the probability distribution of this be $\mathbb{P}_n \equiv Pr(X = n)$, with the usual properties such as $\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{P}_n = 1$.   Furthermore, use the standard definition of the **probability generating function** of this random variable as
$$
G(z) \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb{P}_n z^n
$$
(Note that if we summed to infinity, it would be equivalent as it only has support up to $N$).  Finally, summarize the probability distribution by the vector $\mathbb{P} \equiv \{\mathbb{P}_1, \mathbb{P}_2,\ldots \mathbb{P}_N\}\in\mathbb{R}^N$.  Note that typically the conversion between $\mathbb{P}$ and $G(z)$ is done with a z-transform.

**Stochastic process for $X$:**  In reality, the random variable $X$ evolves as a continuous time stochastic process $X_t$ for $t\geq 0$.  The process is a continuous-time markov chain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain) with some infinitesimal generator $\mathbb{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$

Denote $\mathbb{P}_n(t) \equiv Pr(X_t = n)$, stacking the vector of probabilities at any particular point in time as $\mathbb{P}(t)$.  With this, given some initial condition of the probability distribution $\mathbb{P}(0)$, the evolution of the probability distribution is given by solving the Kolmogorov Forward Equation as a system of $N$ ODEs,
$$
\frac{d\mathbb{P}(t)}{d t} = \mathbb{P}(t)\cdot \mathbb{Q},\,\text{subject to }\mathbb{P}(0)
$$
Defining with matrix exponentials, this ODE has the general solution of 
$$\mathbb{P}(t) = e^{t\mathbb{Q}}$$

Of course, I could denote the probability generating function of $X_t$ as 
$$
G(t, z) \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_n(t) z^n
$$

Just to be clear: The typical properties of the probability generating function, $G(t,z)$, only apply to the non-time dimensions, i.e. $z$.

---

Up until now, everything is completely standard and follows the usual definitions.  My basic question is whether we can write an expression for the evolution of $G(t,z)$ either directly, or as a partial differential equation that I could solve numerically.  Why would this be useful?  Because $\frac{d^K G(t,1)}{ d z^K}$ are the factorial moments of the random variable $X_t$ for a fixed time $t$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Probabilities_and_expectations

**Version 1 of Question**: From $\mathbb{Q}$ is there a way to write a differential equation for $G(t,z)$ directly?

**Version 2 of Question**: is there any clean way to write/simplify $G(t,z)$ in terms of $e^{t \mathbb{Q}}$ (other than the obvious, direct unsimplified substitution into the definition)?  Feel free to use an eigen-decomposition $\mathbb{Q} \equiv U D U^{-1}$ so that $e^{t \mathbb{Q}} = U e^{t D}U^{-1}$ for some diagonal $D$

**As a simple example:** the telegraph process with switching intensity $\lambda > 0$ has $N=2$ and infinitesimal generator
$\mathbb{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}-\lambda & \lambda\\ \lambda & - \lambda\end{bmatrix}
$.  If we started in state $1$ with certainty, i.e., $\mathbb{P}_1(0) = 1$, then with a $G(t,z)$ for this $\mathbb{Q}$, we could find the evolution of the moments over time by taking the derivatives of $G(t,z)$ at $z=1$.  Also, see http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/TransientMM1questa.pdf for an example of this with a particular stochastic process (albeit one with an infinite support for $n$).

---

One last point: if you prefer to work with the characteristic function, the moment generating function, or anything else with an equivalence to the the probability distribution function, that is fine.

Comment: Why stop the series defining $G$ at $n=N$ the number of states? What is $\mathbb P_n$? What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Did Thanks for responding.  My general problems have a a finite number of states, $N$.  As the probability of $n > N$ is $0$, doesn't this stop at $N$? I guess it doesn't hurt to write this as infinite.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}_n(t)$ is the probability of the random variable being $n$ at time $t$.  $\mathbb{P}(t)$ is the vector of all probabilities.

Comment: There's an inconsistency: the MC is declared to be over $N$ states but the generating function explicitly assumes the states are the natural numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n, \ldots$.  Please edit the question to clear this up.  Note that if $G$ really is a sum over the states, then it's just another way of writing down $\mathbb{P}(t)$, which seems like a rather trivial (and pointless) change of notation. What is the purpose behind this?

Comment: @whuber Sorry if I have made an obvious mistake... As an example of the moment generating function for a finite state probability distribution, see this derivation for the binomial distribution: http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/MATHSTAT/5binomgf.pdf  I changed it to sum to infinity, but as the probability distribution wouldn't have support above $N$, I don't think it matters.

Comment: Your reference describes moment generating functions, as you say.  They have nothing to do with what you wrote down in your question, which makes it at present quite mysterious.  Currently you appear to confound states with moments, but they are totally different things.  Perhaps you could edit it to include a small, simple, explicit example of $\mathbb{P}$ and $G$?

Comment: @whuber  Thanks.  I changed "generating function" to "moment generating function" in the question, but I think the formula was correct.  My apologies for making this unclear.  I am not sure how I can write this any other way?  At any time $t$, there is a probability distribution which we could take moments of (fixing $t$).  I want to see the evolution of those moments, so I wanted to see if I can come up with a PDE for the moment generating function instead of the PDE for the evolution of the probability distribution itself.

Comment: The formula makes no sense, because (in a comment) you have defined $\mathbb{P}_n$ to be a *probability* rather than a moment. It would help to write down $G$ explicitly for the $\mathbb Q$ that you specified: that might clear up what you're really asking about.

Comment: @whuber, thank you.  See if my comments help.  This is about finding moments of a probability distribution evolving over time.  I can't write down the formula for $G$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ much simpler without ugly and confusing notation as it is a sum over the resulting vector of solving the KFE with $\mathbb{Q}$.  If there is a way to write it down in a cleaner way, it may be the crux of my quetsion.

Comment: Your question still cannot be properly understood, because it explicitly confuses the probability vectors with the moments. I cannot determine the source of this confusion nor how to address it, so I must ask you to make further edits before re-opening the question.

Comment: @whuber  Sorry, I was trying to say that I wanted the moment generating function (no mention of actual moments there, except as an example of what you could do with the moment generating function).  See my latest change.  I am 100% sure this is a valid question, and that I somehow poorly communicated it before.

Comment: I am supposing it is valid, which is why I have pressed you for clarifications!  I appreciate your ongoing efforts.  Changing mgf to pgf makes much more sense. (Although it is technically correct to sum to infinity, seeing that is still a little jarring since previously you explicitly limited the states to $N$ in number: the notational mismatch raises red flags.)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time on it (and apologize for confusing my generating functions when I tried to clarify earlier).